# Why don't work Shell extension with more than two parameters and ImageMagick

Tags: image, shell, imagemagick, netlogo

I have a problem with Shell extension with more than two parameters . 
I use NetLogo 5.0.5, the shell-extensions and ImageMagick.
I need to execute this shell command 
 shell:exec "convert" "prova.jpg" "-crop" "60x60+10+10" "cropProva.jpg"

But don't work : "Parametro non valido - -crop\r\n".
I am unable to find the correct syntax so that NetLogo don't recognize the input parameters I'm trying to pass to the command.

If anybody could help me through this, that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked just fine for me in NetLogo 5.1 on Mac OS X 10.9.4:

```
observer> show file-exists? "cropProva.jpg"
observer: false
observer> show (shell:exec "/usr/local/bin/convert" "prova.jpg" "-crop" "60x60+10+10" "cropProva.jpg")
observer: ""
observer> show file-exists? "cropProva.jpg"
observer: true
```

Not sure what you and I are doing differently.

Have you been able to use `convert` this way successfully with any combination of arguments? Or is it only this particular combination of arguments that doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but I'm curious what actually helped you about it?